# download excel file from cgi container server through python3.5

Tags: python, cgi

I want to download my excel file which is there in server(CGI Container) through python. I'm able to download the processed data as in json format txt file.

```
def downloadJsonResult(finalJson):
    print ("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    print ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST.xls")
    print
    print   ("""

    """+str(json.dumps(finalJson)))
```

I have saved the processed data in excel, now I want to download it from the client browser. Saving to server is not necessary, only download is required from client side.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Am sorry.I didnt get you.Can you please explain.